# Can resources requested via AJAX be proxied using a PHP-based script?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, proxy

I was wondering if it's possible for a PHP-based proxy to handle AJAX data.
I'm trying to make one or use a ready-made script.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more with an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

Your client-side javascript can make an AJAX request to a same-domain server side script (e.g. PHP in this example), the PHP script could then make a request to a third-party url, process it however, and then return the result to the original client-side javascript.

If you can provide some additional detail, I, or someone else, may be able to provide a more concrete solution/explanation.

EDIT: See http://developer.yahoo.com/javascript/howto-proxy.html for an excellent explanation of the process.

Answer (score 1):

[AJAX Request using PHP as a proxy](http://devtreats.blogspot.com/2011/01/cross-domain-ajax.html)

Answer (score -1):

AJAX data isn't different from any other kind.